# Spring: ManyToOne: Modificar clave ajena en una tabla sin alterar la tabla que referencia

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, update

Tengo una aplicación de spring + JPa en la que he mapeado 2 tablas: "Local" y "sector" con una relación N:1. Local podría ser "Carnes Paco" y el sector "Carnicería".

La relación la he hecho así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="locales")
public class Local {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(length=3, columnDefinition = "integer default 1", nullable = false)
    private int turnoActual;
    
    @Column(length=3, columnDefinition = "integer default 1", nullable = false)
    private int turnoUltimo;
    
    @Column(length=50, nullable = false)
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name="localesRelacionados", length=50)
    private String relacionados;
    
    @Column(length=75, nullable = false)
    private String direccion;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean isDeleted;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sector_id")
    private Sector sector;
    
    
    //*******************//
 

    public Sector getSector() {
        return sector;
    }
    public void setSector(Sector sector) {
        this.sector = sector;
    }

... y los otros Getters y Setters
```

Cuando actualizo un local desde PostMan, lo hago así:

```
http://localhost:9000/locales/local/2/update
```

...y en el body:

```
{
    "turnoActual": 0,
    "turnoUltimo": 1,
    "direccion": "Mercado Central, puesto 8",
    "id": 2,
    "relacionados": "3,4,5,6",
    "nombre": "El Mero Espectador",
    "sector": {
        "id":5
    }
}
```

Y la respuesta que obtengo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En principio, todo sale como yo quiero: El local actualiza su campo "sector_id" y el registro correspondiente de la tabla "sector" no se ve modificado.

La pega es que en la respuesta de postman no estoy obteniendo el objeto "sector" al completo, sino solo el mismo campo que le he especificado.

Y después de todo este rollo, mi pregunta:

¿Cómo hago para actualizar el sector_id de un Local pasando solo dicha ID y que en la respuesta aparezca el Local con su Sector asociado al completo?

Muchas gracias ya por adelantado!ç

EDITO:

Este es mi LocalDAO

```
@Transactional
public Local update(Local local) {
    manager.merge(local);
    return local;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución ha pasado por modificar "LocalDAO". No sé si es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero cumple su cometido:

```
@Transactional
public Local update(Local local) {
    Sector sector = new Sector();
    sector = manager.find(Sector.class, local.getSector().getId());
    local.setSector(sector);
    manager.merge(local);
    
    return local;
}
```